# Post Click Redirect to Custom URL instead of Single Post Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, filters, redirect, actions

I have a custom post type called "articles". When an article link is clicked, I want to redirect them to custom URL(this URL is saved in the database as custom field) instead of the single page. How can I do it? I couldn't find an action hook/filter for it?

Comment: Are you in control of the templates? You could just replace the permalink function with the custom field.

Comment: @JacobPeattie No. I want to do this whole site. Archive pages, widgets, etc. Everywhere.... So this won't work and I don't like touch theme & plugin files for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For redirect to custom url you need to change post detail link to custom url. You simply remove post link and apply custom url.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_field('link'); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

In my case "link" is custom url.

Comment: I want to do this whole site. Archive pages, widgets, etc. Everywhere.... So this won't work and I don't like touch theme & plugin files for this purpose.